# Lazy Loading in UIScrollView with Data from SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

In my iPad application, I've made a segmented control and one segment of which -when clicked- displays a long list (about 300) with images and labels from the local SQLite database. This is taking a lot of time to load and puts the app activity to halt while it's loading all of it from the database.

Although I've applied an activity indicator for the time being, but that looks very shoddy. Can anyone tell me how to apply Lazy Loading in a way that *When the button is clicked to open that view*, instead of loading all the content at once, it fetches only the content that's displayed on the content initially (about 9 images with lablels).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was too fast with that. Do a sqlite query starting at index `current`limit 10 (or 20) and then advance from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement paging on the list. Load first 25 item and then add button ("Next 25") on tableFooterView, which will load another 25.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you might have a better chance.

A `UITableViewCell` loads cells one at a time(gives you the index of the item it is trying to load), so if you use a table view, it will only load the number of items that it needs to display.  You tell it how many items there are, how tall they are, etc.

It also reuses cells, so it gives a lot better performance than creating 300 different views in memory at a time.

A UIScrollView doesn't know about your "items", so it lets you push as many items as you want into a view, and then adds a scroll bar. No optimization here for memory usage, or database access.